# Excel VBA dowload file using the InternetExplorer object

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a VBA code that is currently successfully logging into a website and further navigating to other pages of the website and scraping data that I need.

I now need to navigate to a page (no problem), fill a textbox with a query (no problem) and click on a 'download' button (no problem). This then prompts a popup to download a file (open/save/cancel). My requirement is to save this file without user interaction - the macro should save the file in a predetermined directory.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? I couldn't get SendKeys to work at all.

```
Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium

sURL2 = "http://somewebsite.com/query.asp?"

With appIE
    .Navigate sURL2
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

'code to enter the query in textbox and click on download file button
    appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")(0).Value = Sheets("UserEntry").Range("L37")
    appIE.Document.getElementsByName("btnSubmit")(203).Click
    Application.SendKeys "%{s}"

Set appIE = Nothing
```

Edit: Even if I could get SendKeys to work, I need to 'save as' the file automatically, not just 'save' it in the Downloads folder.

Comment: You could try to either: a) enter tabs to get to the appropriate button and then enter the directory name via `SendKeys`, or b) use `WinHttp.WinHttpRequest` to send a web request and get a response. If you can inspect what it is sending when logging in on Chrome/IE, you might be able to do it this way.

Comment: @BrownishMonster, I think I will study and try the WinHttp.WinHttpRequest idea. Do you think I would still be able to first login, and then navigate and then download the file using that method?

Comment: I'm not sure, depends on how they are posting the login credentials back. You can try to inspect this in chrome/IE. You might need to write the credentials after the url such as `www.example.com?user=MyUser&PWord=PW`, but it depends on what parameters they send back. You might have to retrieve cookies on each response and set them on each request.

Comment: @BrownishMonster ok, my next question is, how do I download using your method? Please assume that I have no predetermined URL. The URL gets dynamically generated when I click on dowload

Comment: you can download the response, which I expect would be the file itself. As for the dynamic URL, I honestly do not know. If some part of the URL is static and the dynamic part is an identifier, you can try and find the identifier in one of the other responses. I have done both, automated IE and used the WinHttpRequest (or maybe some other variant) and found the latter to be less erratic. The automation way gives errors randomly.

Comment: @BrownishMonster I have this code, the response of which I expect the file download, but gives the html of the download page itself
`WHTTP.Open "POST", fileUrl, False`  
`WHTTP.send strSQL`  
  
`FileData = WHTTP.responseBody  

If WHTTP.Status = 200 Then  
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")  
    oStream.Open  
    oStream.Type = 1  
    oStream.Write WHTTP.responseBody  
    oStream.SaveToFile FilePath, 1  
    oStream.Close  
End If`  

Am I on the right path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163878/discussion-between-brownish-monster-and-shoaib-mohamed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working, thanks to the approach suggested by @BrownishMonster

I used WinHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1

I also used Fiddler to investigate what the browser was sending in the POST requests and then made VBA do the same

```
Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

'This is to POST the login info and login to the site
WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send loginString

'This is to POST the download info and download the file
WHTTP.Open "POST", fileUrl_XLSResult, False
WHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.send downloadString

FileData = WHTTP.responseBody

'This is to save the file in the location MyFilePath
If WHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    oStream.Open
    oStream.Type = 1
    oStream.Write WHTTP.responseBody
    oStream.SaveToFile MyFilePath, 1
    oStream.Close
End If
```